# periodic executions with tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, timing

I have written a messaging program and I have hit a problem when testing it.

If I want to send messages at different time intervals, say 100, 200 and 300 milliseconds the program takes the first time and applies it to all messages, but if I include the `after` within a loop it sends the messages at varying speeds from 3 to 419 ms?

Could someone advise how I can apply different waiting times to different messages?

```
global running
        i_ref = 0
        items = self.Translist.curselection()

        for i in items:
           i_ref = int(i)
           if(int(transList[i_ref].tTimer) <= 0):
               pass
           else:
               if running == 0:
                   self.retrans = self.window.after(transList[i_ref].tTimer, self.Enter)
                   self.TranButton.config(state = 'disabled')
               else:    
                   running = 0
                   self.window.after_cancel(self.retrans)

           system('echo "%s %s 0x%s %d 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s 0x%s" >/dev/pcan33' %
                (transList[i_ref].msgType,
                transList[i_ref].canType,
                transList[i_ref].canID,
                int(transList[i_ref].DLC),
                transList[i_ref].tData0,
                transList[i_ref].tData1,
                transList[i_ref].tData2,
                transList[i_ref].tData3,
                transList[i_ref].tData4,
                transList[i_ref].tData5,
                transList[i_ref].tData6,
                transList[i_ref].tData7))
```

This is the function code so far, it is called via button press.

Answer (score 0):

`after` only guarantees to run something sometime *after* the given time, not exactly at the interval specified. If you specify 100ms, it could be 100ms, it could be 101 or 200 or anything else. It is not a real time, high resolution timer. In a system with a light load, it's usually pretty close.

Remember that tkinter runs in a single thread and can only done one thing at a time. If you schedule something 100ms in the future, and then you start running code that takes 200ms to finish, the timer can't run anything until that code is finished, so even if you request 100ms, it will be 200ms or more since it has to wait for the other code to finish.